# How do I assign a variable to an object, not a reference to it?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, variables, reference

```
$a = some object;
$b = another object;
function do_some_stuff() {
    $c = $a;
    $b->a_property = $c;
}
do_some_stuff();
echo $b->a_property; # Undefined, becuase $c was deleted when the function exited.
```

When I type `$b->a_property = $c`, I want the PHP interpereter to do `$b->a_property = $a`. How do I do that, if I'm unable to assign it to `$a` directly?

My actual code is:

```
function setup() {
    $playerHeroes = [];
    $enemyHeroes = [];
    foreach ($entities as $object) {
        if ($object->team == "player") {
            $playerHeroes[] = $object;
        }
        else if ($object->team == "enemy") {
            $enemyHeroes[] = $object;
        }
    }

    foreach ($playerHeroes as $object) {
        $object->target = $enemyHeroes[array_rand($enemyHeroes)];
    }
    foreach ($enemyHeroes as $object) {
        $object->target = $playerHeroes[array_rand($playerHeroes)];
    }
}
```

I sort through a list of entities in the game as either being on the player's team or being on the enemy's team. Each hero must target a hero on the opposing team. When the `setup` function exits, `$object`, `$playerHeroes` and `$enemyHeroes` get destroyed. The `->target` properties are accessed later, and it's `null`. How do I make it so that when I assign a variable to a reference of an object, it assigns it to the object itself?

**EDIT:** I want the variable to change when the object changes, so cloning/copying by value is not an option.

Comment: you are missing a way to get those $entities into your function. As well you are missing a return.
You could do `function setupt(&$objectA, &$objectB)` or something alike with `$entities`

Comment: Either use `global $a,$b;` or set parameters as `do_some_stuff($a,$b)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to echoing the comments from @IvoP and @mega6382, it's worth noting that the problem you're having is not a "solvable" one per se. That's because what you're running into is fundamental to how objects work in PHP. You can learn all about it at [http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php).

> One of the key-points of PHP 5 OOP that is often mentioned is that "objects are passed by references by default". This is not completely true. This section rectifies that general thought using some examples.
>
> A PHP reference is an alias, which allows two different variables to
> write to the same value. As of PHP 5, an object variable doesn't
> contain the object itself as value anymore. It only contains an object
> identifier which allows object accessors to find the actual object.
> When an object is sent by argument, returned or assigned to another
> variable, the different variables are not aliases: they hold a copy of
> the identifier, which points to the same object.
> (hat tip to @tomzx)

You'll likely do better to rearchitect your code to deal with this or use a language whose default behavior is call-by-value like C or Java.